# Magento 2 Import Visual Swatch and Text Swatch Attribute Options Programatically

Tags: swatches, color-swatches, magento2.4.3.p1, visualswatch

I have an attribute with attribute ID 'color'. Which has options with visual swatches. and another attribute with ID 'material' which has options with Text swatches.

Now for the 'color' attribute I need to add options with swatch image or color code programatically. Also add the option labels stores wise.

For the 'material' attribute I need to add the option labels and description store wise.

Please give me some idea regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Code something like the below.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\AttributeFactory;

class ColorImport
{
    private AttributeFactory $attributeFactory;
    
    public function __construct(AttributeFactory $attributeFactory)
    {
        $this->attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var ProductAttributeInterface $model */
        $model = $this->attributeFactory->create();
        $model->loadByCode(Product::ENTITY,'color');
        $data = [];
        $data['optionvisual']['value'] = ['option_0' => ['Black', 'Black']];
        $data['swatchvisual']['value'] = ['option_0' => '#000000'];
        $model->addData($data);
        $model->save();
    }
}
```